# Auto Center and Keep Aspect Ratio of Image in Div

Tags: css

I m trying to center an image in a div while keeping the aspect ratio - I m using this code but somehow its not aligning the item in the center (top/bottom center). If possible using only CSS.

The size of the image is not known since its using max widths!

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L41wpza6/2/

```
#imageHolder {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
line-height: 400px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

#imageHolder img {
 max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Any help is appreciated! I am not sure what I am missing to make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L41wpza6/4/)**

You should use `display: inline-block;` to `#imageHolder img` to vertical-align middle.

CSS display inline-block property allows elements to flow like inline elements but respect properties, such as width, like block elements and you can use display Inline-block to set vertical-align middle.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imageHolder">
    <img src="http://www.discoverjb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IMG_1399.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#imageHolder {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
#imageHolder img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display: inline-block; /* Instead of display: block; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! why doesn't display: block work though? will be marking this as the answer shortly once its available

Comment: @user3448267 Simply because `vertical-align` property is **not** applicable to block-level elements. (Only to inline level elements and `table-cell`s).

Comment: Heads up: to not only vertically but also horizontally center the image, I needed to add `#imageHolder { text-align: center}` because `margin: 0 auto` didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

for one looking for horizontally center.

Solution of @sibbl worked, but there is still some pixels on the top of image in horizontal case.

I have imporoved @Anoymous code

HTML:

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/400">
</div>
<div class="imageHolder">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/800">
</div>
<div class="imageHolder">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/800">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageHolder {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.imageHolder img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduc1102/L41wpza6/43/)