# Div with aspect ratio - how to center image inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I have 1:1 ratio `div` and would like to center the image inside of it both vertically and horizontally. How can I do this?

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 {
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.aspect-ratio-1-1 div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-1-1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Center and Keep Aspect Ratio of Image in Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794901/auto-center-and-keep-aspect-ratio-of-image-in-div)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a technique that works in virtually all browsers by setting the margin to auto, position to absolute, and the top/right/bottom/left to zero:

```
img {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-1-1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another technique uses CSS3 transforms:

```
img {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
img {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-1-1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's not forget **flexbox**

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 {
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.aspect-ratio-1-1 div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:orange;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-1-1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```